# Change styles using reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the next situation. I should change styles depending by a state.
In my case I change backgroundColor:

```js
if (selectedRowKeys.length > 0) {
  document.querySelector("thead tr th:nth-of-type(4)").style.background =
    "red";
} else if (selectedRowKeys.length === 0) {
  document.querySelector("thead tr th:nth-of-type(4)").style.background =
    "gray";
}
```

The code works, but appears a issue when i select a checkbox, after that open dropdown from left corner and click `Select Odd Row`, because the background color should change to `gray`, but it still `blue`, or  in this case the `selectedRowKeys.length === 0` is true, because i set `setState({ selectedRowKeys: [] });`. 
My question is,how to change the background  color in the case that i described above? And why the condition: `document.querySelector("thead tr th:nth-of-type(4)").style.background ="gray";` does not work in my situation?

**DEMO**: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-selection-ant-design-demo-vl9cd?file=/index.js:2021-2055

Answer (score -1):

In your codesandbox, in `line 78` inside `onSelect` handler, you need write `newSelectedRowKeys` to state:

```
onSelect: changableRowKeys => {
  let newSelectedRowKeys = [];
  newSelectedRowKeys = changableRowKeys.filter((key, index) => {
    if (index % 2 !== 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  setState({ selectedRowKeys: newSelectedRowKeys }); // <= Here
}
```

And you need change `else if` statement in `line 43`:

```
if (selectedRowKeys.length) {
  document.querySelector("thead tr th:nth-of-type(4)").style.background =
    "red";
} else {
  document.querySelector("thead tr th:nth-of-type(4)").style.background =
    "gray";
}
```

You don't need `else if`, just use `else`. I hope you understand my answer.